# Puma not logging when running daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, puma, puma-dev

When running Puma as a daemon (i.e. using the `-d` flag), Puma does not seem to log to the location specified by `stdout_redirect`.

Has anyone seen this behavior before and if so, found a workaround to generate the proper log files for Puma (specifically with the `stdout_redirect` in place, and specifically for a Ruby on Rails application)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `stdout_redirect` is not working is because `config/puma.rb` is never run when you run `rails server -d`. You can demonstrate this for yourself by changing the port number or even introducing a syntax error in the file.

Puma runs as a Rack server and is thus launched by the Rack middleware. The [Rack code](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/d15dd728440710cfc35ed155d66a98dc2c07ae42/lib/rack/server.rb#L423) just uses the core Ruby `Process` class to detach the process:

```rb
def daemonize_app
  Process.daemon
end
```

Unfortunately, `Process.daemon` does two things by default:

1. Changes the current working directory to root ('/').
2. Redirects stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`.

So, when the Puma server initializes, all process output is binned and since `/config/puma.rb` doesn't exist, puma falls back to its hardcoded default settings.

You can actually demonstrate the behavior you want if you temporarily hack the `rack` code to override the chdir behaviour:

```rb
def daemonize_app
  Process.daemon(true)
end
```

If the first parameter to `.daemon` is `true` it does not change the current working directory, and thus the `config/puma.rb` gets run.

Short of some kind of ugly monkey-patch to Rack, a (possibly also ugly) workaround would be to skip the `-d` option and roll your own in `config/puma.rb`. For example:

```rb
# ... rest of the puma config

return unless ENV['DAEMONIZE_PUMA'].present?

puts 'Running puma as a daemon...'
Process.daemon(true)
```

Then:

```
% export DAEMONIZE_PUMA=true
% rails server
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Running puma as a daemon...
% tail log/puma.out
=== puma startup: 2021-07-17 10:03:37 +1200 ===
```